# remove extra vertical spacing between minted environment and verbatim environment

Tags: minted, vertical-spacing

I'm using minted for code highlighting. Sometimes I need to typeset code followed immediately by an error message, like the following

```
some code
error: blah blah
```

It isn't appropriate to apply code highlighting to the error message, so I'm using verbatim for that:

```
\begin{minted}{haskell}
some code
\end{minted}
\begin{verbatim}
error: blah blah
\end{verbatim}
```

But that adds a vertical space, like this:

```
some code

error: blah blah
```

I can get rid of the vertical space using \vspace with a negative length between the two environments, for example

```
\begin{minted}{haskell}
some code
\end{minted}
\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{verbatim}
error: blah blah
\end{verbatim}
```

but that subtracts a little too much space. What is the appropriate thing to do here?

Comment: Maybe play around a bit with values for `\vspace` like `-\topsep`, `-\parskip`, maybe `-10pt` or `-5.8mm` or something.

Comment: Thanks Marijn, I tried that already and the problem is that the amount varies depending on how full the page is. If nothing else works then I can experiment with each one to find the right negative length, but this is for a book and there are probably 50 cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `escapeinside` to remove highlighting for a part of the minted block. This functionality is intended to let LaTeX handle the formatting of the text within the escape delimiters. However, it is still more or less verbatim, the font is monospaced, special characters like ` or % or ' are printed normally, and linebreaks are taken into account.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=~~]{haskell}
some code
~Prelude.head:42:23: empty list
 when calling recursively MyModule.scan.go:2009:12 and MyModule.scan.view:2009:7
 when calling MyGUI.promptString:1234:321~
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marijn! This is even better than what I was asking for because it allows me to do highlighting of code fragments in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical space turns out to be twice `\topsep` plus `\partopsep`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\nospacebetweenenvs}{%
  \vspace{-\glueexpr(\topsep+\partopsep)*2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{haskell}
some code
\end{minted}
\nospacebetweenenvs
\begin{verbatim}
error: blah blah
\end{verbatim}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{haskell}
some code
\end{minted}
\nospacebetweenenvs
\begin{verbatim}
error: blah blah
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\texttt{some code}\\
\makebox[0pt]{\vrule width 6cm height0pt depth 0.1pt}\texttt{error: blah blah}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg! When I tried this, the gap between environments was reduced a little too much, to about 90% of the gap between lines of code - close, but not perfect.

Comment: @dsannella It may depend on the document class and other factors.

Comment: egreg yes, probably. I'm using tufte-book. Anyway, I'll use the solution from Marijn because it does even more than I asked for. Thanks for your help!